# Does a Haitian need a visa to travel to Cuba from Port-Au-Prince, Haiti?

Tags: visas, cuba, haitian-citizens

I am Haitian, living in Haiti.

Answer (score 2):

While you need a visa, it's Cuba so there are loopholes. Everything has loopholes, that's what socialism is built on, I still remember. Check [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=HT&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=CU&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C) for more:

> Visa required, except for Passengers with a Tourist Card
>   (Tarjeta del Turista) issued to visitors traveling as
>   tourists.
>
> - Tourist Cards (Tarjeta del Turista) must be obtained prior
>     to arrival in Cuba. They are  available at:
>
>   - Cuban Embassies or Consulates;
>   - Authorized Airlines;
>   - Travel agencies.

As per Havana Times [Is a Tourist Card the same as a Tourist Visa?](http://www.havanatimes.org/?p=13111):

> Mexicana, Cubana and other carriers usually require that the Cuban Tourist Card be purchased from them, at the airline check-in counter, before departure to Cuba.

While I can't find the information for Haiti, I have found this to be true from reports on TripAdvisor for Mexico, the [consulate in columbia](http://www.cubadiplomatica.cu/colombia/ServiciosConsulares.aspx):

> You can also purchase the visa or tourism card in the following places:
>
> - If you travel by the airlines AVIANCA, COPA or CUBANA DE AVIATION , at the EL DORADO airport of Bogota, at the time of checking.

So you probably want to buy a plane ticket from [Cubana](http://www.cubana.cu/) to Havana or Santiago de Cuba. That's what you'd do anyways since no other company flies Haiti-Cuba direct. As per this TripAdvisor [thread](https://www.tripadvisor.ca/ShowTopic-g147270-i91-k9582808-Ferry_Haiti_Cuba-Cuba.html) there are no ferries either (2016 summer).

Comment: I would need sources for that especially since it's the national airline. I also edited further. Everything points to being able, even required to buy it at check in from the airline.